# I already have a running android app. I want to add a layout xml file for a fragment for landscape view

Tags: android, android-studio

I already have a running android app. I want to add a layout xml file for a fragment for landscape view.Now if i try to add a xml file with the same name, it is not allowing me to add a new xml file with the same name.But i want a seperate xml for portrait and landscape. I am currently using android studio version 1.2.2

Comment: If you want to separate the layouts, why would you want to create two files with the same name, making them indistinguishable? Create different files and switch between the layouts. (To be honest, I doubt this is the correct way to do it)

Answer (score 1):

Create a new directory `layout-land` and put your xml file with same name in it.

Strucutre:

```
.....
.....
>src
>asset
>layout
>layout-land // put your files for landscape orientation here
......
......
```

For more read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#Compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a new layout resource folder 'layout-land' and in there store all your landscape layouts.

Tutorial here: [Landscape Layouts](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-landscape-layout-example/)

Information here: [Android Guide: Supporting different screens](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Answer (score 0):

YOu have to create a folder called `layout-land` as they tell in the qualifier list in the docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new *Android resource directory* named `layout-land` under the `res` (resource) directory.
2. Create a new *Layout XML File* with the same name under the `layout-land` directory.

[image]